# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, global, local

I got a local error at first, and when I applied `global` to my code, I got a syntax error.

```
def get_data():
  try:
    source = someURL
    data = requests.get(source)

    try:
      with open('data_file.csv', 'a') as file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=['Column'])
        writer.writerow({'Column':data})
    except:
      pass
  except:
    pass
```

First, I got an error of `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`, then I added `global data` above the 2nd `try`. And now I got `SyntaxError: name 'data' is assigned to before global declaration`

I tried to solve it by applying other people's solutions but with no luck. How would you fix it? Thanks.

**Update:** `data` may have issue getting the value. When there's no value, an error will occur on the `writerow` line. But if I added `except: None` after the first try for the intention of returning None instead, as shown below:

```
def get_data():
  try:
    source = someURL
    data = requests.get(source)
  except:
    None
```

It will generate a local variable error: `local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`. And the only way I have to do is to define `data` as `global`. I'm confused if I'm even on the right path. Or should there be any way to do rather than using `except: None`? Thanks.

Comment: Did you declare `data` before the function definition anywhere? By the way the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment` shouldn't have come up with the code you have. Can you tell which line was the error pointing to? better yet, can you post the entire error stack trace?

Comment: @SiddharthaRT It points to the data variable in {'Column':data}. I was playing around and the error stack doesn't show up anymore. But it just hits `except` directly

Comment: @SiddharthaRT I declared it inside the 1st `try`, nowhere else

Answer (score 0):

The 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment' error indicates that 'data' has not been assigned when it is being called in Line 9 of your code. Either 'data' is defined outside of the get_data() function, or the initial try-block in which 'data' is defined is not being called.

I was able to get this code to run as expected -- double-check that your code is indented correctly and that there are no other formatting errors.

The following code functions as expected:

```
def get_data():
    try:
        source = someURL
        data = requests.get(source)

        try:
            with open('data_file.csv', 'a') as file:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=['Column'])
                writer.writerow({'Column':data})
        except:
            pass
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: It works fine except when `data` couldn't fetch any data, and it hits the first `except: pass` because it cannot write row.